# Problemas with width cell in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a strange problem with the width in UITableView. When I create a UITableView with a CellView. Inside I put a view with trailing and leading with 8 side by side. But when I change de device, de Content View stay strange and if I close the Xcode and restart it, then de layout works. When I compile my app the View stay strange again and if a do a scroll down then de UICell adjust self automatic. What can be? Look the sequence of screens:

PS: This problem happens in xcode 10 and 10.1 beta.

1) I Create layout with iphone SE selected
[image: I Create layout with iphone SE selected]

2) I changed the device to 8 then take a look in the right constraint
[image: I changed the device to 8 then take a look in the right constraint]

3) I only restarted the xcode and the layout works again
[image: I only restarted the xcode and the layout works again]

4) When I compile the app, the layout stay strange again
[image: When I compile the app, the layout stay strange again]

5) If I do a screen down, then de layout works again
[image: If I do a screen down, then de layout works again]

Comment: None of that really matters. The Xcode display of constraints in Interface Builder is buggy sometimes. All that matters is what happens _when the app runs_. If the interface looks right and there are no warnings of constraint issues in the View Debugger, you're fine.

Comment: How are you rounding the corners?

Comment: @matt I don't think so, because if I setup xcode to iphone SE and then I compile and run in a iphone SE de layout works fine. And this happens for the others sizes to. But I will take a look in the warnings.

Comment: If you have to change the storyboard before running in order to get the right interface, then the problem is the opposite: you don't have enough constraints. You need to use constraints so that it looks okay on _every_ size. But, again, the best way to understand what's going on is to use the View Debugger.

Comment: @matt  I'll try check, Thanks.